# How to properly cleanup incorrectly initialized object?

Tags: java, oop, class-design

*I was asked this question in an interview.*

There is a class, lets call it `A`. It has a default constructor and it initializes  2 different connections in its constructor.

Methods `initDB` & `initSocket` creates a DB connection and a socket connection and saves them in an instance field. *They are just an example. They could also be file open or anything else.*

Lets say a client instantiates an instance of this class. Now `initDB` executed successfully, but `initSocket` threw exception. So the object creation was aborted. But the DB connection was not closed prior to the exception. This resulted in a resource leak. How would I tackle this kind of resource leak?

E.g.

```
class A {
    public A(){
        this.dbConnection = initDB();
        this.socketConnection = initSocket(); // throws exception
    }
}
```

My initial answer was that I would not initialize these in constructor but in a separate `init()`. He countered by suggesting that this could be a legacy class, and I have been asked to maintain this. In which case I need to somehow clear the resource leak. How would I approach this problem?

*I got stumped because instance creation threw an exception I lost any kind of reference to those connection fields. So I cannot call `close()` on them. But they will still be present in the OS level (this is my guess).*

***Note 1***

As stated by Interviewer, **I cannot change the behavior of the already written constructor.** I can extend or do something around it, but cannot change the code.

***Note 2***

I think interviewer was not looking for explicitly any code that would handle this scenario. Would any JMX stuff help? I took a jibe at it & then we moved on. For those who think this is a very good question, I think interviewer knew this is not a general practice and probably would not be able to answer.

Comment: If it throws, you can can catch it and dispose of it inside of the `catch`

Comment: @VaughanHilts, No. I did asked for that explicitly and he refused it straightaway. Basically the constructor is now written. And I cannot modify it. I can extend the class or do something else, but cannot modify the constructor.

Comment: Why not just use try catch like `try { this.socketConnection = initSocket(); }catch(Exception e) { this.socketConnection = null;}`

Comment: @SudhirOjha, Because I cannot modify the code in the constructor. See my reply to VaughanHilts above.

Comment: Are methods `initDB()` and `initSocket()` also _legacy code_ ? Can you change **any** of the legacy code? Or do you have to write a new class that extends class `A` ?

Comment: I suspect that this might be your interviewer's pet question where they know a trick (that might not even be valid Java or requires mucking about with the `JAR` file) and you have to guess it.

Comment: You're going to have to change something. You could poke the byte code, I guess, if you want. ;)

Comment: The _exceptions_ thrown by methods `initDB()` and `initSocket()`, are they **checked** exceptions or **unchecked** exceptions? If they are checked exceptions then they must be declared in the constructor for class `A`, as in `public A() throws ...`.

Comment: @Abra Yes you are right, but even in that case, I will be able to close DB connection if socket connection threw exception. I will add some other notes on the question.

Comment: is it possible that you can use class B instead of class A wherever class A is used?

Comment: You can't wrap a `super` in a try.

Comment: The correct answer is "constructors should not do any work"

Comment: @SvetlinZarev other way to say is, it is time to refactor legacy code or rewrite portion of it.

Comment: @SvetlinZarev, that I already suggested to him. Say for example in a Spring application I would have used something like `PostConstruct`.

Comment: I have a feeling the interviewer probably wanted you to ask some questions and get more info -- and something would lead into a solution. I posted a couple thoughts as an answer. Some are very viable, even if not "good", specifically ByteCode modification _should_ always work.

Comment: @VaughanHilts, that is a very possible scenario. And I think interviewer knew this. I did cleared the interview, even though I was not able to give proper answer. This could be one of those question where he is looking for my approaches only. I don't know this for sure though. That's why I posted the question here.

Answer (score 0):

We have a few options here...

1. Box the thing off somewhere else. It's clearly problematic legacy code. Perhaps this "blob" which has access control issues can be moved into something some other process that can communicate with the rest of the system via RPC. You are better off doing this if the system is horribly broken. You can extend it other ways, such as composition; but if it's so sealed off you can't get it it, then you're boned
2. Use byte code modification. You could do this and you could get enough leverage to get what you need. ByteBuddy would come in handy for this. I wouldn't do this personally but hey, sometimes desperate measures call for desperate solutions...
3. If you can influence `initDB`, then you can decorate the return value with something else. For example, let's supposed it was some from some base class we *did* control or some other method we controlled, then we could perhaps do something like this

```
Connection initDb() {
  try {
    this.wrappedProvider.initDb();
  } catch(Exception e) {
     // .. destroy the connection...
  }
}
```

... and then since you can influence this, you can change the *effective* semantics of it.

4. Can you influence the "Connection" of "A"? How does it get "A"? If it gets it  from some DI container or something you *can* influence, then you can sub out the implementation for that class for something that "times out" if not talked to or initialized in some given time. Hacky, sure but without more info that's the best we're going to get...

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1:

Provided that:

1. You can extend class A, and then use instances of class B instead,
2. method `initSocket` is overridable (not final nor private)
3. field `dbConnection` is accessible from class B (not private)

You can override method `initSocket` to close the `dbConnection` in case of an exception:

```
@Override
protected Socket initSocket() {
    boolean ok = false;
    try {
        Socket result = super.initSocket();
        ok = true;
        return result;
    } finally {
        if (!ok) {
            dbConnection.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Solution 2:

Provided that:

1. You can extend class A
2. method `initDb` is overridable (not final nor private)

You can wrap your A object in another class, and save the connection so that it can be closed in case of an exception:

```
class B {
    private static ThreadLocal<Connection> CONNECTION = new ThreadLocal<>();
    private final A delegate;

    public B() {
        boolean ok = false;
        try {
            delegate = new A() {
                @Override
                protected Connection initDb() {
                    Connection result = super.initDb();
                    CONNECTION.set(result);
                    return result;
                }
            };
            ok = true;
        } finally {
            if (!ok) {
                Connection cnt = CONNECTION.get();
                if (cnt != null) {
                    cnt.close();
                }
            }
            CONNECTION.set(null);
        }
    }
}
```